# Possible cases with set of four non negative integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Consider set of four non negative integers $S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4:s_i\in\mathbb{Z^+\cup\{0}\}\}$. Then there are the following possible broad cases:

$1$. All four integers are equal.

$2$. These integers are pairwise distinct.

$3$. There are three distinct integers.

$4$. There are two distinct integers appearing twice each.

$5$. There are two distinct integers with one appearing three times.

**Question:** What are all the possible cases with these four integers in $S$ considering the above broad cases?

**Case $1$.** $s_1=s_2=s_3=s_4$

**Case $2$.** $s_i\neq s_j$ for all $i\neq j$

**Case $3$.** a. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_4= s_1$.

b. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_4= s_2$.

c. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_4= s_3$.

d. $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_1= s_2$.

e. $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_1= s_3$.

f. $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_1= s_4$.

g. $s_3\neq s_4$, $s_3\neq s_1$, $s_1= s_2$.

h. $s_3\neq s_4$, $s_3\neq s_1$, $s_2= s_3$.

i. $s_3\neq s_4$, $s_3\neq s_1$, $s_4= s_2$.

**Case $4$.** a. $s_1=s_2$, $s_3=s_4$, $s_3\neq s_1$.

b. $s_1=s_3$, $s_2=s_4$, $s_4\neq s_3$.

c. $s_1=s_4$, $s_2=s_3$, $s_4\neq s_3$.

**Case $5$.** a. $s_1=s_2=s_3$, $s_4\neq s_1$.

b. $s_2=s_3=s_4$, $s_2\neq s_1$.

c. $s_3=s_4=s_1$, $s_2\neq s_1$.

d. $s_4=s_1=s_2$, $s_3\neq s_1$.

I think there should be $24$ subcases in total and in the above there are only $18$ subcases.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you worked it out and got to 18.... regardless of whether or not you did that correctly (in fact, 18 is not correct, since you overcounted ... compare 3a with 3f for example), why do you then say that you feel it should be 24? Where does the idea of 24 come from?

Comment: @Bram28  I though that there are $4!=24$ cases. Can you please help me with this question.

Comment: 4!=24 would make sense if you were to calculate something like the possible orderings of s1 trough s4 ... but that is not what you are doing here.   In fact, the way you go about it in your post is good ... you just overcount a few times for case 3.   For case 3, think about it this way: betwen s1,s2,s3, and s4, you need to have one = relation, i.e. you need to find one pairing out of these 4 objects, So that is 4 choose 2 = 6 possibilities .. rather than 9

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you. So what is the total number of possible subcases? Is it 15?

Comment: Unless I am missing something myself, seems like 15 is correct!

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you. I would request you to write as an answer please.

Comment: In case you are interested, these numbers are called [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) and are usually described as the number of ways to _partition_ a set of $n$ distinct elements.  $15$ is indeed the $4$th Bell number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good!  You just double-counted some subcases for Case 3. For example, note that subcase 3a is really the same as 3f:  in both cases you have $s_1$ and $s_4$ as the same number, while $s_2$ is a second distinct number, and $s_3$ a third distinct number yet.  To further see that these two subcases are really the same, it is helpful to indicate *all* identities and  between the non-identities between the $4$ integers, as in both cases we have:

$s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1= s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$.

This notation also suggests a way to correctly count the number of subcases for Case 3: out of the $6$ identity/non-identity statements, there is exactly one identity statement, and 5 non-identity statements. So, you just need to find one pair of integers out of the $4$: once you have done so, your subcase is completely fixed:  the pair of integers form an identity claim, while for the others you have all non-identity claims.

Doing this, you get:

A. $s_1 = s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 \neq s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. (your 3d and 3g)

B. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1= s_3$, $s_1 \neq s_4$, $bs_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. (your 3e)

C. $s_1 \neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 = s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. (your 3a and 3f)

D. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 \neq s_4$, $s_2 = s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. (your 3h)

E. $s_1 \neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 \neq s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2 = s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. (your 3b and 3i)

F. $s_1\neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 \neq s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 = s_4$. (your 3c)

Now adding up all subcases gets you to 15.

Comment: +$1$. Thank you for the answer. Please list the subcases of case $3$ amongst my attempt which are correct.

Comment: @Max You're welcome. Added the explicit sub-cases

Comment: Thanks for the edit. . In your part C, $s_1 \neq s_2$, $s_1\neq s_3$, $s_1 = s_4$, $s_2\neq s_3$, $s_2\neq s_4$, $s_3 \neq s_4$. So since $s_1=s_4$, so $s_3\neq s_4$ gives $s_1\neq s_3$ which we already have. So the condition $s_3\neq s_4$ is redundant I think. Please check. According to your nice indication of identities and non-identitites what will the cases $4$ and $5$ look like?

Comment: So many of the non identities in you edit I think are redundant. Please check.

Comment: Some can be derived, yes, but by indicating all the identities and non-identities, I am sure to not fall into the trap of double-counting, and it gives an immediate method for exhaustively and systematically covering all cases. Redundancy is often very helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful.